# Prove that for any graph G the number of vertices multiplied by the lowest degree is $\le$ the number of edges multiplied by 2

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

For this proof. I know that number edges is half the sum of the degree sequence since vertices are connected only once. So if the edges are doubled that means, it will definitely be more than the number of vertices. I am having trouble showing how multiplying by the lowest degree with the number of vertices will always be less than the number of edges doubled.

Comment: You know that the sum of the degrees is equal to twice the number of edges? But you can't figure out why twice the number of edges is $\ge$ the number of vertices times the lowest degree? In other words, you can't figure out why the sum of all the degrees is $\ge$ the number of vertices times the lowest degree? Is that what's troubling you?

Comment: Basically. I have a hard time trying to show why the number of vertices times the lowest degree will always be smaller or equal.

Comment: You have a hard time showing why the number of vertices times the lowest degree will be smaller than or equal to the sum of all the degrees? This has nothing in particular to do with graph theory. Whenever you add up a bunch of numbers, the sum of all the numbers will be greater than or equal to the least number times the number of numbers you added. In symbols: if $d_1\le d_2\le \cdots\le d_n$ then $d_1+d_1+\cdots+d_n\ge nd_1.$

Comment: So how do you prove that it is always the case that the sum of all the numbers will be greater than or equal to the least number times the number of numbers you added?

Comment: I would prove it by induction. But why do you need a proof, when you **know** it's true? If you buy 5 toys, and the cheapest toy cost you \$3, do you need a mathematical proof that you must have spent at least \$15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ G(V,E)$ be our graph, where $V$ is the set of vertices, and $E$ is the set of edges.

Set $ |V|:=n$ and $|E|:= m $. Then it holds that:

$$ \sum_{v \in V} deg(v) =2m  \quad (\star)$$

Set $ \displaystyle \delta(G):= \min_{v \in V} deg(v) $. What we want to prove is : $ n \delta (G) \leq 2m $.

Using $(\star)$ this follows immidiately, indeed

$\displaystyle 2m = \sum_{v \in V} deg(v) \geq \sum_{ v \in V} \delta(G) = \delta(G) |V| = n \delta(G)$.

Comment: Can you explain why $\sum \delta(G) = \delta(G) |V|$ is true? What if there is a degree sequence (2,2,5,6) then $\sum \delta(G) = 4$ but $\delta(G) |V| = 8$ .

Comment: because $ \delta(G)$ is "independent" of $v$, in the sense that it is a number, so we can move it out of the sum.

Comment: Do you mind giving an example with numbers?

Comment: check dtldarek answer, the first equality, we do exactly the same thing

Comment: So if I have degree sequence (3,3,3,4,5). |V| = 5, $\delta(G) = 3 $. How does |V| * $\delta(G)$ equal the sum of the number of min degrees?

Comment: Just do the calculations....$ |V| \delta(G)= 15$ and $ \sum_{ v \in V} \delta(G) = \sum_{v \in V} 3 =  3 \sum_{ v \in V} 1 = 3 |V| = 15 $.

Comment: So $\displaystyle \sum_{v \in V}$ = # of vertices? That was my confusion.

Comment: yeap...in general $ \sum_{k=1}^n 1= n $

Answer (score 2):

$$|V|\times\min_{w\in V}\deg(w)=\sum_{v\in V}\min_{w\in V}\deg(w)\leq\sum_{V\in v}\deg(v)=2|E|$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @onesevenfour In your example, (number of vertices)=5 and (min degree)=3, so (number of vertices)$\times$(min degree) = 5$\times$3=15 and (sum of min degrees) = 3+3+3+3+3 = 15. How do you get 3*3??

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Handshaking lemma

Now see whether the LHS of the equation in this link is at least the number of vertices multiplied by lowest degree.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma